# regular expression not working when provided in double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use regular expession in javascript but it is not working. My custom control contains property called RegEx which is provided by user and I need to validate the input value against this regex. As properties in JS will be in double quotes("") the regualr expression fails(case -1). Case 2 succeeds thought both the cases regualr expression is same, the only difference is case- 1 it goes as double quotes. can somebody tell me why it is not working.
RegexExp="/^\d{5}$/"- at my aspx page

```
var value = "11111";
     if(value.toString().search($(element).attr('RegexExp')) != -1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

  var reg = /^\d{5}$/;
     if(value.toString().search(reg) != -1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is that JQuery you are using? $() is not a standard function, so dig up the documentation of whatever it is and see what it says there about the .attr() function.

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
var reg = new RegExp($(element).attr('RegexExp'));
```

Update: you also need to strip the / characters, as these shouldn't be given to the RegExp constructor:

```
var regexExp = $(element).attr('RegexExp');
var reg = new RegExp(regexExp.substring(1, regexExp.length - 1));
```

Comment: i tried the below sample example but still it is not working-

var v1 = "22222";
var reg = "/^\d{5}$/";
reg = new RegExp(reg.substring(1, reg.length - 1));
alert(v1.search(reg));
it still gives -1

Comment: You can't do that because you need to escape backslashes in literal javascript strings, like this: var reg = "/^\\d{5}$/". But you don't need to escape the backslashes if you read the string directly from the page.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the code that you posted is part of the function from the return statements, but if it is not, your first problem is that `return` is not allowed to be used out side of functions.

In any case, try the following.  You can create a RegExp from a string by using its formal constructor

```
value.search(new RegExp($(element).attr('RegexExp')));
```

Also, you do not need to use `toString()` on value since it is already a string and your code is unnecessarily verbose.  The following is equivalent to your first `if else` statement

```
return value.search(new RegExp($(element).attr('RegexExp'))) != -1;
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to be able to pass in an expression as "/[expression]/" or "/[expression]/gi", you can do the following:

```
var toRegExp = function(regexString) {
    var expression   = regexString.substr(1),        // remove first '/'
        closingSlash = expression.lastIndexOf("/");  // find last '/'

    return new RegExp(
        // Expression: remove everything after last '/'
        expression.substr(0, closingSlash), 
        // Flags: get everything after the last '/'
        expression.substr(closingSlash+1)
    );
}

....

value.search( toRegExp($(element).attr('RegexExp')) );
```

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't* use a custom attribute to hold a regular expression.  Second, "RegexExp" is redundant — that's like saying "regular expression expression".  Third, to convert from a String to a RegExp, you have to wrap the string with `new RegExp()`; JavaScript is not weakly typed.  That said, assuming that the regular expression isn't being set server-side, I'd recommend using [jQuery's data API](http://docs.jquery.com/Core#top).  It has the added advantage that it *can* store regular expression objects directly.

To set:

```
jQuery.data($(element).get(0), "regexp", /^\d{5}$/);
```

To get:

```
jQuery.data($(element).get(0), "regexp");
```

But ultimately, what you really want is the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  It does everything you need and then some.  Incidentally, it uses the data API internally to work its magic.

- [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: Granted that depending on the available libraries there may be a better ways to do it, but there is nothing wrong with using a custom attribute to hold arbitrary data.

Comment: Woah, hey now... that -1 was uncalled for.  The HTML specification does not allow custom attributes.  What he's trying to do is guaranteed to make every page on which this technique occurs invalid.  The work-around I gave is the generally accepted method of resolving the issue, and it has the added advantage of coming with all kinds of extras built-in, like email validation, credit card validation, and so on, most of which cannot be easily expressed with a simple regular expression.  Have you seen the regular expression for emails?  It's more than a full page long!

Comment: Ya, email is ridiculous.  I'll take it back since I suppose that I should have said that "there is nothing wrong with using a custom attribute," *if you specify a custom DTD*.  For example: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/

Comment: This is true, though honestly, even then, I still don't really recommend it in the general case because there's almost always a better alternative and the extra work of involving a custom DTD is rarely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The /.../ syntax is used to declare a regular expression object in Javascript, so you shouldn't use that to specify a regular expression pattern, it should be just `regexp="^\d{5}$"` as the attribute.

The search method takes a regular expression object as parameter, so you have to create a regular expression object from the string that you get from the attribute:

```
var reg = new RegExp($(element).attr('regexp'));
if (value.toString().search(reg) != -1) {
```

(You see the similarity with your second case?)

Or as a single expression:

```
if (value.toString().search(new RegExp($(element).attr('regexp'))) != -1) {
```